# Breeze 1.4.6 - inlinecount on projection query being applied AFTER paging

Tags: breeze

After upgrading to breeze 1.4.6 targeting the Web API 2, I believe that inlinecount on a projection query is being applied AFTER the paging.

For example if I specify take(5) then *inlinecount is returning 5 even though the filter matches say 100 records*.

**Can you confirm that this is a problem with breeze 1.4.6?**

Looking at the code in QueryHelper it looks like this happens only when the odata query is modified to support such things as "selects" of "nested" properties.

I have been able to reproduce the problem in a failing unit test:

```
/*********************************************************
* inlineCount of projected paged products
*********************************************************/
test("inlineCount of projected paged products", 2, function () {

    // Filtered query
    var productQuery = EntityQuery.from("Products")
        .where("ProductName", "startsWith", "C");

    // Paging of that filtered query ... with inlineCount
    var pagedQuery = productQuery
        .select("ProductName, Category.CategoryName")
        .orderBy("ProductName")
        .skip(5)
        .take(5)
        .inlineCount();

    var productCount, pagedCount, inlineCount;
    var em = newEm();
    stop(); // going async

    // run both queries in parallel
    var promiseProduct =
        em.executeQuery(productQuery)
            .then(function (data) {
                productCount = data.results.length;
            });

    var promisePaged =
        em.executeQuery(pagedQuery)
            .then(function (data) {
                pagedCount = data.results.length;
                inlineCount = data.inlineCount;
            });

    Q.all([promiseProduct, promisePaged])
        .then(function () {
            ok(inlineCount,
                "'data' from paged query should have 'inlineCount'");
            equal(inlineCount, productCount,
                "'inlineCount' should equal product count");
        })
        .fail(handleFail)
        .fin(start);
});
```

A fix would be very welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

This has been fixed in the Breeze 1.4.7 release, available now

### Previous post

This is a bug in Breeze 1.4.6 involving select and inlinecount.  It has already been fixed in the source and dll's on GitHub. ( You can go ahead and pull the dll's directly ).  This fix will also go out in the 1.4.7 release, sometime next week.

Comment: Yup thought I saw the fix in master

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what fix you are looking for.  From the Breeze docs (I added the highlighting) -

> **inlineCount** *Integer* - 
>   Only available if 'inlineCount(true)' was applied to the query. Returns the count of items that would have been returned by the query before applying any skip or take operators, but **after any filter/where predicates would have been applied**.

Comment: You're right - my bad. I need to correct my question. I should have said inlinecount is being applied AFTER paging is applied. So for example if I've asked to take(10) then the inlinecount is return 10 even though the filter matches say 100 records.